# How to share only one screen in browser video calls?

Tags: xorg

I am using a laptop with an external monitor. Xorg is running using xrandr to setup the monitor and the laptop's display next to each other. I am thus able to move windows from the monitor to the laptop display and vice versa.

If I try to share my screen in Chrome or Firefox, it shares all screens at the same time (i.e. the image of my monitor next to the image of my laptop display). The shared image is then way too wide and thus too small for other people to see.

In the image below, you see my external monitor on the left and my laptop display on the right.

[image]

I would hope to be able to share my external monitor only. On the laptop display I would like to have the video call application present.

Options I know of:

1. Using xrandr, disable my laptop display while sharing. The laptop display is then unusable though.
2. Using X, start its own display per screen. I then will not be able to move windows from one screen to the other without restarting applications though.
3. I could share single application windows. This is cumbersome though if you switch between applications.

**Is it possible to share only my external monitor while still being able to use my laptop's display?**

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been [fixed](https://webrtc-review.googlesource.com/c/src/+/156067/) in Chromium but apperently the fix hasn't been released yet.

> Latest Chromium 83 (dev/unstable) fixes this issue
>
> source: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437507#c74

[This](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/screen-sharing-linux-chromium-fix) article provides an overview of the problem and links to potential [work-arounds](https://github.com/Ashark/hliss).

You may also find this SE article useful: [Sharing your desktop with Google Hangouts, dual monitor and GNOME Shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152435/sharing-your-desktop-with-google-hangouts-dual-monitor-and-gnome-shell)